# How to reuse the exiting instance of webdriver for different classes

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have gone through the existitng questions on this site, but unable to resolve 
the following issue

Tools:Junit,IntelliJ,Java Language

//SetUp Class

```
public class SetUpTest {
public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
public static void setUpTest() throws InterruptedException
{
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.ABC.co.uk");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

}


//Test1
public class HomePageTest extends SetUpTest {

    @Test
    public void titleTest()

    {
        assertTrue(driver.getTitle().startsWith("ABC"));

//Test2
 public void merchandisingTest() throws InterruptedException {
    @Test
    public void merchandisingTest()
    {

         driver.navigate().to("http://ABC.co.uk/deals");
 assertThat(driver.getPageSource(),containsString("deals"));
```

I have tried running the tests with @TestBefore but still two browser windows are opened
one for Test1 and the other for Test2.I have also used @Suite.SuiteClasses
but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code

```
public class BaseTest{
    public WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeSuite
    public void startDriver(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5l, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.ABC.co.uk");
    }
}

public class HomePageTest extends BaseTest{
    @Test
    public void titleTest(){
        assetTrue(driver.getTitle().startsWith("ABC"));
    }

    @Test
    public void merchanisingTest(){
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.ABC.co.uk/deals");
        assertTrue(driver.getTitle().startsWith("deals"));
    }
}
```

Also, you are running this using TestNG XML I guess, within which the @BeforeSuite method is called only once

Comment: Hi rsakhale, I am using Junit, so @BeforeSuite is not applicable in this case. The problem is not resolved by using implicitwait.

Comment: Oh, then if you are maintaining single class throughout your test you can make use of @BeforeClass which I am not sure would work. But it may be a good time to switch on TestNG to achieve many benefits.
May be you can also make use of FactoryMethod to create Driver whose instance is created only once - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern
In this you maintain the copy of your driver on object level and always call getDriver method which gives the original created instance rather creating new instance all time